# Are foods that are surface treated with alcohol haram?

Tags: halal-haram, food, alcohol

When I lived in Italy I used to have bread from a company called Mulino Bianco. Here is a link to one of their bread's ingredients: https://www.mulinobianco.it/pan-bauletto-integrale?yxpt-from=search

The ingredients are just your regular bread's ingredient (wheat, water, salt, yeast, oil). but they said they add alcohol to the surface after making bread (as preservative I believe).

Would this make the bread haram?

Answer (score -1):

AssalamuAlaykum. In response to your query about the bread from Mulino Bianco, the primary concern seems to be the addition of alcohol as a preservative.
In Islam, consumption of alcohol is expressly forbidden, and By-Products of alcohol are also forbidden.  To avoid the confusion between halal and haram food, it's recommended to avoid such bread or dishes that may create ambiguity. Opting for readily available halal bread alternatives is a safer and simpler choice. Additionally, it is best to use alternative halal bread which is easily available with Halal Certification.
However, it's always important to seek advice from a trusted religious authority or scholar in such matters as interpretations may vary.
Wa-alaikumussalaam